# Django - how to change view based on option chosen in select dropdown from template

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to display a graph that is responsive to an option chosen by the user from a select form. However, I'm finding that the graph isn't acting responsive when I choose other options besides 'BTC'.

relevant main.HTML:

```
     <div class = "container">
        <form method = "POST" action = "">
          <select name = "coin-select">
            {% for coin in coin_lst %}
            <option value="{{ coin }}">{{ coin }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </form>
     </div>
     <div class = "container">
        {% autoescape off %}
        {{ graph }}
        {% endautoescape %}
      </div>
```

relevent view.py:

```
def initial_data(request):
    coin_lst = []
    for x in focused_df.coin:
        if x not in coin_lst:
            coin_lst.append(x)

    def close_vs_redditComments():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            coin =  str(request.POST.get("coin-select"))
        else: 
            coin = 'BTC'
        closeVSredditComment = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
        closeVSredditComment.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df[df.coin == coin]['time'], y = df[df.coin == coin]['close'], name = "closing price"), secondary_y = False)
        closeVSredditComment.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df[df.coin == coin]['time'], y = df[df.coin == coin]['reddit_comments'], name = "reddit comment volume"), secondary_y = True)
        return(plot(closeVSredditComment, output_type = 'div'))

    context = {
        'coin_lst': coin_lst,
        'graph': close_vs_redditComments()
    }
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Judging by the code, I believe you’re trying to re-render the graph when a different coin is selected. Default is BTC. If that’s the case, then the above code is working as expected. The view is responsible for rendering only once, i.e. when the url is called. The server can not re-render the view. What you are trying to do is going to be handled client side, not server side.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using AJAX in Django with your current HTML.

You can read the details for implementation in this article:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html